# Ordering by different column depending on value of another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random, sequence

[image: TABLE CONSIST PASSAGE AND NORMAL QUESTIONS]

There are two type of questions there 1.Passage and 2.Normal questions.
usally in test i want to pick random questions which consist `type_id=0` in that if `type=1` question come the the next passage should be relates to that question(Comprehension question should come in sequential). By using the below query i am able to get the questions

```
SELECT *      
FROM tbl_testquestion 
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN type_id=0 THEN RAND() 
        WHEN type_id=1 THEN qu_id 
    END ASC
```

> all the passage questions are coming last

and i have limit of 40 questions for test and in the table i have 50 passage questions and 70 Normal questions.

> How can i write a query to call passage questions in between normal
>   questions.

**EXAMPLE**

1.who is the president of America.?(type_id=0)

2.A,B,C are 3 students Aname is "Arun" B name is "Mike" C name is "Jhon"(type_id=1)
who is C from the above passage

3.A,B,C are 3 students Aname is "Arun" B name is "Mike" C name is "Jhon"(type_id=1)
who is A from the above passage

4.Who is CEO of Facebook.?(type_id=0)

Form the Above **4** question we will pick random if Question **1** comes in that `rand()` no problem when the question **2** comes in the `rand()` the next question should be sequential. it means next question should be **3** after that passage questions completed it should switch back to `rand()` functionality

Comment: Why do you need in random sort? You can use simply ORDER BY qu_id

Comment: @Abdul Waheed, you can reorder rows in your table such as you need it and use ORDER BY qu_id :) but in this case you need to add new column number of ticket in your table and your query will look same: SELECT * FROM tbl_testquestion WHERE NUMBER_OF_TICKET=RAND() ORDER BY qu_id

Comment: if a passage question is made of 3 questions: 1) in the 40 questions limit, it counts for 1 question or for 3 questions? 2) if the group of 3 questions is ordered in example as 38th, can it be broken and cut off the last of three or the group should be keeped complete? 3) if group must keeped, limit will become i.e. 41 questions or must strip off normal questions above? 4) if there are not normal questions to strip off?

Comment: @MtwStark 1) it counts as 3 questions.
2)can be broke.(good question)
3) limit is fix 40. the passage group can be broke.
4)i did get exactly this point.. but there is No chance of not having normal questions, but there is a chance of not having passage questions for a course

Comment: @AbdulWaheed: It is better you can create sqlfiddle( http://sqlfiddle.com/ ) and tell what you need from the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the design of your database should be improved, but I’m going to answer your question as it stands.

I think I have a rather simple solution, which I can express in portable SQL without CTE’s.

It works this way: let’s assign two numbers to each row, call them `major` (an integer, just to be safe let’s make it a multiple of ten) and `minor` (a float between 0 and 1). For type 0 questions, `minor` is always 0. Each type 1 question relating to the same passage gets the same `major` (we do this with a join with a grouped subselect). We then order the table by the sum of the two values.

It will be slow, because it joins using a text field. It would be better if each distinct `passage_description` had an integer id to be used for the join.

I assume that all type 0 questions have empty or null `passage_description`, while type 1 questions have them non-empty (it would make no sense otherwise.)

I assume you have a `RAND()` function which yields floating values between 0 and 1.

Here we go:

```
SELECT u.qu_id, u.type_id,
       u.passage_description, u.passage_image, 
       u.cat_id, u.subcat_id, 
       u.question, u.q_instruction, u.qu_status
  FROM (
   SELECT grouped.major, RAND()+0.001 AS minor, t1.* 
     FROM tbl_testquestion t1
     JOIN (SELECT 10*FLOOR(1000*RAND()) major, passage_description 
           FROM tbl_testquestion WHERE type_id = 1 
           GROUP BY passage_description) grouped 
     USING (passage_description)
     -- LIMIT 39 
   UNION
   SELECT 10*FLOOR(1000*RAND()) major, 0 minor, t0.* 
     FROM tbl_testquestion t0 WHERE type_id = 0
) u ORDER BY u.major+u.minor ASC LIMIT 40;
```

With the above query without modifications, there is still a small probability that you get questions of only one type. If you want to be sure that you have at least one type 0 question, you can uncomment the `LIMIT 39` on the first part of the `UNION`. If you want at least two, then say `LIMIT 38`, and so on. All type 1 questions related to the same passage will be grouped together in one test; it is not guaranteed that all questions in the database related to that passage will be in the test, but in a comment above you mention that this can be “broke”.

**Edited:**

I added a small amount to `minor`, just to bypass the rare but possible case in which RAND() returns exactly zero. Since `major` goes by tens, the fact that `minor` might now be greater than one is immaterial.

Comment: It worked sure i will upgrade my database structure with `passage_id` thank you i really appriciate your time.

Comment: I edited the answer to deal with the extreme low-probability case that `RAND()` has returned exactly 0 __AND__ a group of passage questions have received the same integer `major` as a type 0 question. I bet it would have never happened in the entire lifecycle of your application, but nevertheless...

Comment: @AbdulWaheed you said that passage questions (groups) should range from 0 to 2, AND that a group should be always completed except if it exceed the 40 questions limit. In this solution this is not respected, the LIMIT in the 1st part of UNION seems not to work in mysql 5.7 but if it will, it limits only 'questions' not 'groups' so there is not real control on how groups are truncated

Comment: @MtwStark Yes, in MySQL 5.7 you have to enclose the individual SELECTs in parentheses if you want to apply a LIMIT clause to them. That’s an easy edit. As to your other objection, I have myself worked in the context of random selection of test questions and I understood that what the OP wanted was to select some related passage questions for a test and to have them appear together; that a “truncated” group could appear only at the end was not really a requirement, indeed it would contradict the more important requirement of random order. I stated that clearly in my answer and it was accepted.

Comment: take a look at the comments of 1st answer and read the chat. maybe I have misunderstood, but the OP said that if a group would be selected by random, all questions of that group shoud be added (grouped). if a group starts in 38th position (~35-40) and exceed 40 rows limit.. it can be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following, I haven't tested this so, if there are any errors please report back, I will correct them. $r is a random value produced by PHP for this query. You could do $r = rand(); before calling the query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    UNION((
       SELECT *, RAND()*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_testquestions) as orderid
            FROM tbl_testquestion 
            WHERE type_id=0
            ORDER BY orderid
            LIMIT 20
       ),(
       SELECT *, MD5(CONCAT('$r', passage_description)) as orderid
            FROM tbl_testquestion
            WHERE type_id=1
            ORDER BY orderid
            LIMIT 20
    ))
) AS t1
ORDER BY orderid
```

**Explanation**: orderid will keep type_id=1 entries together as it would produce the same random sequence for the same passage questions.

**Warning**: Unless you add passage_id to the table, this question will work quite slowly.

**Edit:** Fixed the ordering (I hope), forgot that MYSQL generates random numbers between 0 and 1.

Comment: Passage questions are not coming in last as well. :( see this is my previous query to select all question by rand(): `select * from tbl_testquestion where cat_id='".$cat."' and subcat_id='".$sub_cat."' and qu_status='1' ORDER BY  RAND() LIMIT 40` now i want to add passage questions in it.

Comment: Do you want random questions followed by N passage questions?

Comment: Ah, now I think I understood a little better. Is there a way to determine how many questions in a passage question series? Don't tell me from the question text.

Comment: Actually NO,if 1 passage question comes in rand() next only same passage questions should come after that all same passage questions done it has to switch to rand() whether it may passage or normal that is system choice.

Comment: Ok, doing another edit, but it would be best if you could redesign your database. Its current design looks like a patch work that would cause performance issues along with these kind of hard to build queries.

Comment: Not working.Same prob all passage questions are coming  sequence in end.what i am looking is passage question should come in between because there is a limit of 40 question and if i have 50 normal questions the passage question will not appear.

Comment: This fix will also fix the previous version, if you prefer that way (random number of questions per passage question). This one will get all passage questions from a passage question series.

Comment: if there is a chance No passage questions in one Course then..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131135/discussion-between-abdul-waheed-and-cem-kalyoncu).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for mysql,
sorry it is not so readable because mysql does not supports CTE like sql-server.

Maybe you can compare with sql-server CTE syntax to the bottom to better understand how it works.

```
select 
    d.*
    , o.q_ix, rnd_ord -- this is only for your reference
from (
        select *, floor(rand()*1000) as rnd_ord -- this is main order for questions and groups
        from (

            select * from (
                select 
                    (@r1 := @r1 - 1) as q_ix, -- this is row_number() (negative so we can keep group separated)
                    passage_description, 0 qu_id, type_id
                from (
                    select distinct passage_description, type_id
                    from tbl_testquestion, 
                    (SELECT @r1 := 0) v, -- this is the trick for row_number()
                    (SELECT @rnd_limit := -floor(rand()*3)) r -- this is the trick for dynamic random limit
                    where type_id=1
                ) p
                order by passage_description -- order by for row_number()
            ) op
            where q_ix < @rnd_limit

            union all

            select * from (
                select 
                    (@r2 := @r2 + 1) as q_ix, -- again row_number()
                    '' as passage_description, qu_id, type_id
                from tbl_testquestion, 
                (SELECT @r2 := 0) v -- var for row_number
                where type_id=0
                order by qu_id -- order by for row_number()
            ) oq

        ) q
) o
-- look at double join for questions and groups
join tbl_testquestion d on 
    ((d.passage_description = o.passage_description) and (d.type_id=1)) 
    or 
    ((d.qu_id=o.qu_id) and (d.type_id=0))
order by rnd_ord
limit 40
```

and this is the more readable sql-server syntax:

```
;with
p as (  
    -- select a random number of groups (0-2) and label groups (-1,-2)
    select top (abs(checksum(NEWID())) % 3) -ROW_NUMBER() over (order by passage_description) p_id, passage_description
    from (
        select distinct passage_description
        from d
        where type_id=1
    ) x 
),
q as (
    -- label questions (1..n)
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by qu_id) q_ix, qu_id
    from d
    where type_id=0
),
o as (
    -- calculate final order
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by newid()) rnd_ord
    from (
        select p.q_ix, passage_description, 0 qu_id from p
        union all
        select q.q_ix, '', qu_id from q
    ) x
)
select top 40 
    d.*
    , o.rnd_ord, o.q_ix
from o
join d on 
    ((d.passage_description = o.passage_description) and (d.type_id=1)) 
    or
    ((d.qu_id = o.qu_id) and (d.type_id=0)) 
order by 
    rnd_ord
```

that's all